# 2-way ANOVA bar graph Using R

Tags: r

How to make a 2-way ANOVA bar graph with 95% CI error bars in R? I had been searching all around but can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way of visualising linear models is through available packages, such as `visreg`. Here's an example with mtcars:

dat <-mtcars %>% mutate(gear=as.factor(gear), carb=as.factor(carb))

```
library(visreg)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
lm(mpg~ gear + carb, dat) %>% visreg
```

[image]

Comment: But thats not a bargraph and it doesnt have error bars